# How to create a fake throw effect?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm learning AS3 and I'm trying to build a little interaction where I can throw a square off the stage. It just need to stay on the x-axis, to be thrown either to the left or right.

I found quite a few tutorials where it involves physics. I don't need anything as complicated as that. With mine, as long as you click down on the square and throw it a bit, doesn't matter how hard that throwing action is, the square will always be thrown off the stage, depending on the direction of your mouse.

I kind of have the idea in my head that the "throw" feel can be done with tween in a movieclip (since it only need to go to either left or right), which will be activated depending on the direction of the mouse.

I apologies if this is a basic question, I have no idea how to start on it. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this as a base class for the object that you want to throw.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class ThrowableObject extends Sprite
    {
        // properties
        public var yv:Number = 0;
        public var xv:Number = 0;

        private var _grabbed:Boolean = false;
        private var _gy:int = 0;
        private var _gx:int = 0;

        private var ox:int = 0;
        private var oy:int = 0;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function ThrowableObject()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _init);
        }

        /**
         * Called on dispatch of Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE
         * @param e Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE
         */
        private function _init(e:Event):void
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _handle);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, _handleClick);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _handleRelease);
        }

        /**
         * Called on dispatch of Event.ENTER_FRAME
         * @param e Event.ENTER_FRAME
         */
        private function _handle(e:Event):void
        {
            ox = x;
            oy = y;

            if(_grabbed)
            {
                x = parent.mouseX - _gx;
                y = parent.mouseY - _gy;
            }
            else
            {
                x += xv;
                y += yv;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Called on dispatch of MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN
         * @param e MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN
         */
        private function _handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            grabbed = true;
            parent.addChild(this);
        }

        /**
         * Called on dispatch of MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP
         * @param e MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP
         */
        private function _handleRelease(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            grabbed = false;
        }

        /**
         * Sets grabbed
         * @param val Boolean representing value to set grabbed as
         */
        protected function set grabbed(bool:Boolean):void
        {
            _grabbed = bool;

            if(_grabbed)
            {
                _gx = mouseX;
                _gy = mouseY;
            }
            else
            {
                xv = x - ox;
                yv = y - oy;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marty, really wish I can say that I understand this, but I dont...and I don't know how to apply this to my project either. Is there a working file that I can take a look at?

Comment: Hey mate, I've prepared a .zip that contains the files you'll need and an example of how to use them. You'll also find a small explanation on the process of setting up a base class in the ActionScript panel on frame 1. Hope this helps. The zip is here: junk.projectavian.com?f=throwable.zip