# AS3: How to make an object follow the cursor when 'mouse down', and then keep moving after release

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, mouse, flash-cs6

Sorry for the weird title, I don't know how to formulate my question in one sentence, which is why I can't search for it.

My question:
Has anyone got an idea, or a tip for what to search for this problem?

I want a MovieClip, lets just say a ball as an example, to follow the cursor when i click on it and hold the mouse button Down (that's the easy part, something like ball.x and ball.y = mouseX and mouseY).

Now when I release the mouse button, I want the ball to keep moving towards where the cursor was heading.

So if I move the cursor fast towards the right side of the screen in an upgoing way, and then release the mouse button, then the ball should continue moving fast towards the right side of the screen in an upgoing way.

I guess I kind of want to track how fast the cursor is moving, AND in which direction. Has anyone got any idea how this can be done, or a searchword???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try looking for `Velocity`. In essence, you need to calculate the speed of horizontal and vertical movement, by comparing previous stored coordinates with the coordinates of the current frame.

Comment: A good search word is "parallax", or "velocity", or "delta per frame". In short, you record mouse position each frame, remember position at previous frame, get delta and store that. Once the mouse button is released, use an enter frame listener to move that ball according to the stored delta. Should do.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!
I found this guide based on those searchwords
http://www.quasiuseful.com/?id=11

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a fake throw effect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433572/how-to-create-a-fake-throw-effect)